# Translation from ARM assembly to LLVM IR

Tags: disassembly

Is there publicly available solution for translation of ARM assembly to LLVM IR?

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation of LLVM ?

Comment: Yes I did. Would you please try to be more specific ?

Comment: I mean, your question is bad. You did not even consider telling us what you already tried. You do not tell us in what your question is linked to reverse-engineering. It totally lack of context. Try to be a bit more explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2008-March/012953.html:

> During Google Summer of Code 2007 I was working on llvm-qemu, which
>   translates from **ARM machine code to LLVM IR** (at basic block level) and
>   via the LLVM JIT to x86 machine code. All source architectures
>   supported by qemu (x86, x86-64, ARM, SPARC, PowerPC, MIPS, m68k) can
>   be translated to LLVM IR this way (e.g. adding support for x86 to
>   llvm-qemu should be almost trivial).
>
> You can find llvm-qemu at http://code.google.com/p/llvm-qemu/